# How to display socket result as string not object in Angular

Tags: angular, sockets, angular12

I am following this tutorial https://blog.briebug.com/blog/making-use-of-websockets-in-angular and it all works. However, the result is always `[object Object]` and I cannot figure out how to get the string value of what I sent displayed.

This is how the content is displayed:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let message of messages">{{ message }}</li>
</u>
```

and this is how the socket is used:

```
messages: Message[] = [];
destroyed$ = new Subject();

constructor(private webSocket: WebSocketService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.webSocket.connect().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  ).subscribe(messages => this.messages.push(messages));
}

sendMessage() {
  this.webSocket.send({ message: this.msgCtrl.value });
  this.msgCtrl.setValue('');
}
```

The tutorial uses the socket: wss://echo.websocket.org. So all it is doing is sending an 'echo' back of what I sent it. How can I display what it is sending back?

Comment: Try {{ message | json }} to see the shape of the message. My guess is you want {{ message.message }}

Comment: thank you! {{ message | json }} worked so I can finally see the result! but now how do I access that in ts so that I can do stuff with it??

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it :-) but you have access to it inside this.messages right?

Comment: Yeah. so my result is now displays something like { "message": "hello" } but what if I just want 'hello'... I am fairly new to angular.

Comment: {{ message.message }} should do the trick ;-)

Comment: Or you could do ngOnInit() {
  this.webSocket.connect().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  ).subscribe(messages => this.messages.push(messages.message));
}

and then you can show just {{message}}

Comment: yayyy!! thank you!!

Comment: ;-) - enjoy coding - Angular rocks!